# I've build a gen_server with Erlang and rebar. Now how do I run it?

Tags: erlang, rebar

Rebar included the framework, `[blah]_sup.erl` and so on.  I added my one external dependency to `rebar.config`.  I added a file to `src/`, which is a gen_server that handles most of the work.  I've added that gen_server file to `[blah]_sup.erl` so the gen_server starts as a child, and starts when the app starts.  Of course I've compiled everything with `rebar compile`.

What do I do now?  I don't know how to start the app!

Comment: For example https://www.metabrew.com/article/erlang-rebar-tutorial-generating-releases-upgrades

Comment: application:start(blah)... maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jr0 suggests in the comment you run:

`application:start(blah).`

However, you need to make sure you add the dependency path first:

`code:add_patha("../deps/<dependency name goes here>/ebin").`

and make sure it' started:

`{ok, _} = application:ensure_all_started(<dependency name goes here>).`

Personally I tend to make a stand-alone module called blah.erl that does the above for me and just call that.

Answer (score 0):

In your local instance, the easiest way is to just run:

```
rebar3 shell
```

This will run your application correctly.

Comment: The OP states that they are using rebar - rebar doesn't have the shell command